# Two targets for one button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom unbutton and I've added two targets too it. If the textfields are empty then one target will act but if the textfields are not empty then the other target will act. But both targets are acting at the same time to the individual button. Can someone help me and explain to me why.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    FirstName.delegate = self
    LastName.delegate = self
    FirstName.addTarget(self, action:"edited", for:UIControlEvents.allEditingEvents)
    LastName.addTarget(self, action:"edited", for:UIControlEvents.allEditingEvents)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if FirstName.text?.isEmpty == true || LastName.text == "" {
        ProgressButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Skip"), for: .normal)
        ProgressButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
        ProgressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Skip(_sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    } else {
        ProgressButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Right2"), for: .normal)
        ProgressButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,31,24,0)
        ProgressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Continue(_sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }
}

func edited() {
    if FirstName.text?.isEmpty == true || LastName.text == "" {
        ProgressButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Skip"), for: .normal)
        ProgressButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
        ProgressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Skip(_sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    } else {
        ProgressButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Right2"), for: .normal)
        ProgressButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,31,24,0)
        ProgressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Continue(_sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }
}

func Continue(_sender: ABProgressButton!) {
    FirstName.resignFirstResponder()
    LastName.resignFirstResponder()
        // Delay the dismissal by 5 seconds
        let delay = 0.85 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        var time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToViewController#2", sender: nil)

        })

}

func Skip(_sender: ABProgressButton!) {
    FirstName.resignFirstResponder()
    LastName.resignFirstResponder()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToViewController#2", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Has `edited()` been called by the time you experience this behavior? And how are you determining that both methods have been called?

Comment: One don't you just assign one function to your button and when user tap that button, your main function executes, it checks a boolean condition if see which of the two sub-functions it should call and calls it if the condition is met?

Comment: You might want to take a peek at this summarizing conventions for capitalization, etc. https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide Classes, structs, and enums are capitalized while methods and variables are in camelCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `removeTarget(_:action:for:)` for the action you've already installed on the button. Check the comments in the header for `addTarget(_:action:for:)`.

Answer (score 0):

When the view generate, the first target add.
When you edit the text, the second target add.
So when you edited the text, the button has two targets.
You need to use remove target in edited()